# Looking for the name of a book with a man and woman attacked by wolves and a young gypsy in danger (possibly for practicing magic)

Tags: story-identification

I don't have much info about this, I can only remember 2 scenes and I'm not entirely certain they're from the same book (only about 95%).

One scene has a man (possibly with a woman with him) attacked on a hill by what I think was a pack of wolves. I remember them riding the same horse, and he's got a sword. I'm pretty sure that this attack was communicated somehow to another person (telepathically or by some kind of magical viewing) who was trying to reach the man to help.

The other scene is of a young gypsy woman who I think got her wagon from her grandmother. She makes potions and see things (I don't remember how she sees). I think she is somehow in danger but I'm not sure how, it may have been for practicing magic.

The book was set in a historical period, possibly early 1800s or before in a British type area. I think it was part of a series and that the author was female. I read the book around 10 years ago. Also I believe it was a paperback copy.

Thanks for any suggestions, this has been driving me crazy for a couple of years!